# Error "The required module 'PackageManagement' is not loaded" when attempting to install or import modules

Tags: powershell

When attempting to install any PowerShell module (e.g. AWS.Tools.Installer) I get the following error message

```
Install-Module : The 'Install-Module' command was found in the module 'PowerShellGet', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module PowerShellGet'
```

So then I run the command `Import-Module PowerShellGet` to get additional information and I get the error message

```
Import-Module : The required module 'PackageManagement' is not loaded. Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PowerShellGet.psd1'
```

When I check the `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PowerShellGet.psd1` file I can see that the `RequiredModules` section lists PackageManagement version 1.4.4.

Note that I have the following versions installed on my local machine

- PackageManagement = 1.0.0.1
- PowerShellGet = 2.2.5

But when I try to install the required version of PackageManagement using the command `Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -RequiredVersion 1.4.4` I'm back to the same problem again and the install fails.

How can I resolve this issue? I know for sure that I was able to install and import modules in the past so I'm not sure what has changed in my PowerShell environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by manually changing the `RequiredModule` section of the file `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PowerShellGet.psd1`

If was changed from

```
RequiredModules   = @(@{ModuleName = 'PackageManagement'; ModuleVersion = '1.4.4' })
```

to

```
RequiredModules   = @()
```

Once that was changed I was then able to install the required version of the PackageManagement module (i.e. 1.4.4) using the command

```
Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -RequiredVersion 1.4.4
```

Then I reverted the file `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PowerShellGet.psd1` back to what it was originally (i.e. specifying version 1.4.4 of the PackageManagement module).

After that, I was then able to install and import modules again as normal.

However, I have no idea how my system ended up in this state in the first place. I know for sure that the install and import functionality was working previously.